# Javascript Tabs with HTML 5 and CSS3 not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to create `HTML` form with `JavaScript` tabs. There are three tabs and I want to hide second and third tab contents in page on load.
This is my Javascript function

```
window.onload = function() {

  // get tab container
    var container = document.getElementById("tabContainer");
    var tabcon = document.getElementById("tabscontent");
    //alert(tabcon.childNodes.item(1));
    // set current tab
    var navitem = document.getElementById("tabHeader_1");

    //store which tab we are on
    var ident = navitem.id.split("_")[1];
    //alert(ident);
    navitem.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
    //set current tab with class of activetabheader
    navitem.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");

    //hide two tab contents we don't need
     var pages = tabcon.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 1; i < pages.length; i++) {
         pages.item(i).style.display="none";
        };

    //this adds click event to tabs
    var tabs = container.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      tabs[i].onclick=displayPage;
    }
}
```

When I run these file in localhost it is working correctly. But I wants to run this file in my server. When I store this file in my server, it is not working. It show all tab contents and not hide second and third tab contents in page load as shown in figure.

[Tabs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP6HN.jpg)
I cant identify the reason. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure?

Comment: Be specific in describing your issue. Why it is not working on server? What issue are you experiencing?